# Cannot get proper user input through scanf char in C

Tags: c, windows

```
int main() {
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
char ch;
float price, amount;


printf("Enter price: $");
scanf("%f", &price);
amount = price * 0.9;
printf("Early payment (Y/N): ");
scanf("%c", &ch);

if(ch == 'n')
{
  printf("Amount due: $%0.2f\n", price);
}
else{
    printf("Amount due: $%0.2f\n", amount);
}
return 0;}
```

it prints everything fine but completely skips the char input part.. and displays the amount somehow. can someone point out the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: it worked... how come?